# "amp;" Precedes $_GET array element (parameter) name

Tags: php, url

The below link is the issue-although the ".amp;" (I am seeing that my link is not appearing as I pasted it when I view this question before posting.  This is exactly what I'm looking to do with my $_GET variable name, remove the amp; from the parameter name)

index.php?SearchResults&SearchString=aliquippa&AllWords=off

The $_GET elements are named with amp; preceding the name I expect.  For example, $_GET[amp;AllWords'] is how the variables are named.  I expect $_GET['AllWords'] format.

All links on my 'site' are built and returned by a standard class function that applies htmlspecialchars to the final return value.  Each link is constructed by a class function specific to the required task and then returned through by calling this standard function.  While all links are returned through the same standard function, I have only 1 link misbehaving.

This link is the first time I've tried taking user input and passing it (redirecting?) back through a $_GET parm.  It's like the &'s are being doubled up.  I am certain the code is not adding a second ampersand.

As a solution, I immediately found and tried htmlspecialchars_decode() against the POST variables.  It made no difference with the name assigned to the $_GET parm.  Other than decoding what was encoded and going through the logic, I'm at a loss for understanding.  The code building the link in error looks the same as the code that is building links that work fine. All links are returned through the standard function, which applies htmlspecialchars.  I would think all links either work or do not work, not a mixture.

Below is the code being used for redirect when the $_GET array contains a parm named 'Search' - this is the code I suspect of injecting the double &'s. I have added writing to a log file in this function and the "double &'s" are present in the return value from
Link::ToSearchResults.

```
if (isset($_GET['Search']))
{
    $this->mSearchString = $_POST['search_string'];
$this->mAllWords = isset($_POST['all_words']) ? $_POST['all_words'] : 'off';

    ob_clean();

    header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
header('Location: ' . Link::ToSearchResults($this->mSearchString, $this->mAllWords));

    flush();
    ob_flush();
    ob_end_clean();
    exit;
}
```

Following is the ToSearchResults function code:

```
$link = 'index.php?SearchResults';
if (empty($searchString))
$link .= '/';
else
    $link .= '&SearchString=' . $searchString;

$link .= '&AllWords=' . $allWords;

return self::Build($link);
```

Following is the return from standard class function Build().  All links are passed through this function before returning to caller.

```
return htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: looks like you need to `urldecode()` somewhere

Comment: It looks like you somehow call `htmlspecialchars()` on already escaped links with ampersands, thus &amp; turns into &amp;amp;. Possibly in the Build method.

Comment: index.php?SearchResults -- this looks strange, why a key-less value? What good can it do?

Comment: @MightyPork It's a valueless key, not a keyless value, and PHP correctly represents it in `$_GET` as a hash key whose value is the empty string. The answer to your latter question should therefore be quite obvious: it's a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you pass values containing '&' through the `Build` method, which is escaping HTML special characters with HTML entities. The resulting link will be of the form:

```
index.php?SearchResults&amp;SearchString=aliquippa&amp;AllWords=off
```

PHP's URL parser does not expect to encounter HTML entities, because they should not be present in URLs; it therefore correctly splits the query string on `&`, treating the trailing `amp;` as part of the key. To solve the problem, do not pass your URLs through `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: That works, thank you.  I'm learning by following a beginning ecommerce book so I'm not sure why htmlspecialchars was used.  However, I'm left wondering why all other links are fine and this one isn't, while all links are returned through the same function.  Beyond the parm names, what is the difference between the above link and this link?  index.php?DepartmentId=1&CategoryId=3 - I've had no problem with links like this.

Comment: @PaulaShaw There's no difference in the links, but there appears to be a difference in the way they're being handled; `Link::ToSearchResults()` takes arguments consisting of query values, then assembles them into a full query string, and passes the result through `Build()`, which then passes it through `htmlspecialchars()`. It's at this last step the problem occurs; presumably, most generated links aren't passed through `Build()`, or are otherwise constructed such that the full query string doesn't go through `htmlspecialchars()` at any point.

Comment: All of my links are returned through the Build function. Which is why I am not understanding how all of my other links work, but this one doesn't. Removing htmlspecialchars has resolved the problem, I've been able to completely debug the search routines with no other link issues caused from the removal. In addition, no link issues have appeared anywhere.  I need to find out why the author used htmlspecialchars on all his links.